# Get all item_types in PaperTrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In PaperTrail I can filter event by "item_type". Is there any way to get all distinct item types? There's nothing in the documentation.

Comment: `PaperTrail::Version.pluck(:item_type).uniq`

Comment: @mr_sudaca, what if there're millions of records in total for, say, 3 distinct models, how slow will that be?

Comment: well, paper-trail adds an index to that column, maybe you can generate some (a lot of) records and then `Benchmark.ms {PaperTrail::Version.pluck(:item_type).uniq}`. I think it won't take that long

Comment: @mr_sudaca, does it create a separate table for item_types?

Comment: no, but you could add a new table... i'll post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up your questions, I think the easiest way to retrieve item types is just looking at which models have the `has_paper_trail` call, but, this won't work with polymorphic models (User - Student - Instructor). But, you asked about a different table to store item types, maybe you can add it. you can override PaperTrail::Version model this way:

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base #(rails <= 4.x)

  after_commit :add_item_type

  def add_item_type
    item_type_object 
      = VersionItemType.where(item_type: self.item_type).first ||
        VersionItemType.new(item_type: self.item_type)
    item_type.save
  end
```

now, you'll need a model class for `VersionItemType` and a migration:

```
create_table :version_item_types do |t|
  t.string :item_type
  t.timestamps
end

class VersionItemType < ActiveRecord::Base #(rails <= 4.x)
  validates :item_type, presence: true
end
```

so, after paper_trail stores each version, it'll add an unique item_item in the new table

EDIT: If you follow this, you'll have to create a rake task or something to fill up the table with stored item_types